# Small multiples plots replicating entire network in each panel in ggraph()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph, tidygraph

I would like to make a small multiples plot of a network using `ggraph`. For each node in my network, I have two features, `feat1` and `feat2`. I would like to visualize the `feat1` for the entire network in one panel, and `feat2` for the entire network in another panel. Each panel should contain all the nodes and edges in the network, in the same position. Eventually I will want to do this for 10-20 features, say.

To solve this kind of problem for tabular data, I would use `pivot_longer()` or `gather` to get the data into long format, and then I would pass the long data to `ggplot()` and use `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()`. `ggraph` and `tidygraph` don't offer graph-variants of `pivot_longer()` to my knowledge, so I'm not sure how to solve this problem. I'm looking for an idiomatic `ggraph`/`tidygraph` solution if there is one.

Here is a hacky solution that I would like to improve on.

```r
library(ggraph)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidygraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(patchwork)
library(tidyr)

gr <- as_tbl_graph(highschool) |>
  mutate(
    feat1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n(), replace = TRUE),
    feat2 = sample(LETTERS[1:8], n(), replace = TRUE)
  ) |>
  mutate_at(vars(feat1, feat2), as.factor)

p1 <- ggraph(gr) +
  geom_edge_link(alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_node_point(aes(color = feat1)) +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual") +
  theme_graph()
#> Using "stress" as default layout

p2 <- ggraph(gr) +
  geom_edge_link(alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_node_point(aes(color = feat2)) +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual") +
  theme_graph()
#> Using "stress" as default layout

p1 + p2
#> Warning: Using the `size` aesthetic in this geom was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` in the `default_aes` field and elsewhere instead.
```

[image]

I also tried to do solve my problem by using `create_layout()` to work with data in tabular data space, where I can use `pivot_longer()`. That attempt is as follows:

```r
layout <- gr|>
  create_layout(layout = 'stress')

# it seems i can pass layouts to ggraph instead of graph objects
layout |>
  ggraph() +
  geom_edge_link(alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_node_point(aes(color = feat2)) +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual") +
  theme_graph()
```

[image]

```r
# pivot the layout data
layout_long <- layout |>
  pivot_longer(
    contains("feat"),
    names_to = "feat_name",
    values_to = "feat_value"
  )

# pivoting messes up class and attribute information so fix it?
class(layout_long) <- class(layout)
attributes(layout_long) <- attributes(layout)

# this sadly doesn't work, presumably because the dimensions of the graph and the layout no longer match
layout_long |>
  ggraph() +
  geom_edge_link(alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_node_point() +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual") +
  theme_graph()
#> Error in `geom_node_point()`:
#> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
#> Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
#> ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (70)
#> ✖ Fix the following mappings: `x` and `y`
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2.9000](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't think your first example is hacky at all. You might want to put the code in an `lapply` or `Map` so that you can run the code for each node attribute without having to rewrite it several times, but the general approach looks good.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to set up a nodes data.frame, perform the pivot there, then feed that into a tbl_graph() call, which allows you to specify separate data frames for nodes and edges.

here follows your example.

```
grnodes <- data.frame(name=  unique(c(highschool$to,highschool$from))) |> mutate(
        feat1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n(), replace = TRUE),
        feat2 = sample(LETTERS[1:8], n(), replace = TRUE)
        ) |>
        #mutate_at(vars(feat1, feat2), as.factor) |> 
        pivot_longer(cols=c(feat1,feat2), names_to='feature', values_to='group')

gr <- tbl_graph(nodes=grnodes,edges=highschool)

ggraph(gr) +
  geom_edge_link(alpha=0.1) +
  geom_node_point(aes(color=group)) +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual") +
  theme_graph() + facet_nodes(.~feature) + geom_node_text(aes(label=name))
```

But this didn't work because ggraph + facet_nodes doesn't seem to work with a long-form data.frame of nodes - it seems to connect only some nodes by their corresponding edges even if the nodes have the same name. Might be worth opening an issue with the ggraph team

Comment: Just opened an issue with the `ggraph` folks: https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/343